# Include Recent Post in Category

Tags: posts, customization, themes, homepage, wp-editor

I use a free WordPress Theme called DefautMag, It has a front page with 3 columns, In the front page settings, I could choose any category to display in any of these columns, But I want to display recent posts in one of them. However, recent post is a widget and not a category. Is there any way that I can add recent posts to the categories so as to select it. 
A slight problem here is, I am not a php programmer and I don't want to break my site, just in case I have to edit the theme to replace one of the columns with recent posts.
I have searched extensively for days now. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought would be to simply add a Category "Recent posts" or "Blog" or something similar and just put all of your posts in the category.

Can you please provide a link to the site in question if that's something you don't want to do?

Comment: sure www.iobservers.com       Recent post shows up in the sidebar, but that's way down under the several categories

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way to solve this and I thought be might help someone someday, so here;
I created a category called Recent Posts, and then I made it a parent category to all the major categories on the site. Then I selected it as a category to be placed in one of the sections. This pulled the most recent posts from the children categories and lined them up right under. Problem solved.